# Do mapping between xml:base attribute and other node values of a xml file using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xinclude

I am having a xml document like below,

```
<chapter xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xml:id="chapter1">
<title>First chapter</title>
<section xml:id="section1">
                <imageobject>
                    <imagedata fileref="images/image1.jpg"/>
                </imageobject>
                <imageobject>
                    <imagedata fileref="images/image5.jpg"/>
                </imageobject>
</section>
    <chapter xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xml:id="chapter2"   xml:base="../foder1/section2.xml">        
   <section xml:id="section2">
                    <imageobject>
                        <imagedata fileref="images/image2.jpg"/>
                    </imageobject>
                    <imageobject>
                        <imagedata fileref="images/image3.jpg"/>
                    </imageobject>
    </section>
    </chapter>
    <chapter xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xml:id="chapter3" xml:base="../folder3/section3.xml">  
   <section xml:id="section3">
                    <imageobject>
                        <imagedata fileref="images/image4.jpg"/>
                    </imageobject>
    </section>
   </chapter>
 </chapter>
```

As in file, there are relative paths to the images in each xincluded file. I want to get the absolute path of the image. For that I am going to combine xml:base value of each chapter with the relative image paths in that chapter. Then I can get all absolute paths to images in each chapter. For that purpose I used following XSLT 1.o file.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<imagepaths>
<xsl:for-each select="chapter/chapter">
 <basepath>
 <xsl:value-of select="@xml:base"/>
 </basepath>
</xsl:for-each>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="*" /> 
</image-paths>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="imagedata">
  <relativepath>
  <xsl:value-of select="@fileref" />
  </realtivepath>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this gives all xml:base values and relative paths separately. It does not provide any mapping between xml:base value of each chapter and relative paths in that chapter. I want to have a mapping between xml:base value and all relative paths in that chapter. How I this mapping should do? I think by having output like below, I can do the mapping and get the absolute path of images. Please help me to get following output with my XSLT. With it I can access all images in section1 by "mainrelativepath" and section2, section3 images by basepath and relativepath nodes.

```
<Imagedata>
    <mainrelativepath>images/image1.jpg</mainrelativepath>
    <mainrelativepath>images/image5.jpg</mainrelativepath>
<chapter>
    <basepath>../foder1/section2.xml</basepath>
    <relativepath>images/image2.jpg</relativepath>
    <relativepath>images/image3.jpg</relativepath>
</chapter>
<chapter>
    <basepath>../foder3/section3.xml</basepath>
    <relativepath>images/image4.jpg</relativepath>
</chapter>
```

Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <Imagedata>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="chapter"/>
  </Imagedata>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*/chapter">
  <chapter>
   <basepath><xsl:value-of select="@xml:base"/></basepath>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </chapter>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="imagedata">
   <relativepath><xsl:value-of select="@fileref"/></relativepath>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<chapter xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xml:id="chapter1">
    <title>First chapter</title>
    <section xml:id="section1">
                    <imageobject>
                        <imagedata fileref="images/image1.jpg"/>
                    </imageobject>
    </section>
        <chapter xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xml:id="chapter2"   xml:base="../foder1/section2.xml">
       <section xml:id="section2">
                        <imageobject>
                            <imagedata fileref="images/image2.jpg"/>
                        </imageobject>
                        <imageobject>
                            <imagedata fileref="images/image3.jpg"/>
                        </imageobject>
        </section>
        </chapter>
        <chapter xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xml:id="chapter3" xml:base="../folder3/section3.xml">
       <section xml:id="section3">
                        <imageobject>
                            <imagedata fileref="images/image4.jpg"/>
                        </imageobject>
        </section>
       </chapter>
</chapter>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<Imagedata>
   <chapter>
      <basepath>../foder1/section2.xml</basepath>
      <relativepath>images/image2.jpg</relativepath>
      <relativepath>images/image3.jpg</relativepath>
   </chapter>
   <chapter>
      <basepath>../folder3/section3.xml</basepath>
      <relativepath>images/image4.jpg</relativepath>
   </chapter>
</Imagedata>
```

Comment: Hi Dimitre..
Thank you very much for your quick response. This is what I was looking for. But you can notice that there is a relative path like "images/image1.jpg" in the xincluding xml file. With your XSLT, it seems like we missed that path. If you can please modify your answer to add that image path also..Sorry I could not mention it earlier. I have modified the new output..Thanks in Advance..

Comment: @vish, I think you made a structural error -- the first chapter includes all other chapters. If this is truly so, then *all* images should belong to the first chapter -- but this is not reflected by the provided desired output. Therefore, if the outermost chapter's images should also be generated, then the question has a notable gap, not explaining what is considered the chapter's imsges and what not. Please, edit the question and provide a non-conflicting explanation and/or revise the wanted output.

Comment: Sorry for late. I changed <xsl:template match="/*"> to <xsl:template match="/"> and produced my desired output. You are awesome..!! Thank you very much again..=)

Comment: Hi, With my solution, I could only get one image path in first chapter. But how I should get all paths when there are several in the outer most chapter?  I have changed my desired output. If you can please guide me to generate that output. I want to differ first chapter image paths from other image paths. I think by having another node like "mainrelativepath", I can complete my purpose.

Comment: @vish, Please,ask a new, separate question. People hate answering for months the next version of the same question. Readers lose enormous amount of good information as an older version of the question gets buried by a newer one.

Comment: Ahh..I got it..I will ask a new question. Thank you..!!